# C++ text to std::vector with a delimeter, when text begins with delimeter

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to split the string "/1/2/3/4" to four parts, ie 1,2,3,4. I am using boost to split the string

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        std::vector<std::string> v;
        //boost::split(v, argv[1], boost::is_any_of("/"));
        boost::split(v, argv[1], [](char c){return c == '/';});
        for( auto i : v )
                std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;

        return 0;

}
```

when I run I am taking an extra empty word in my vector

```
[oracle@localhost split]$ ./a.out /1/2/3/4
 1 2 3 4 
5
```

due to the fact that my word (/1/2/3/4) starts with the delimiter. How do I resolve this issue? I want the vector to hold 1,2,3,4 only.

Comment: Easy solution: after you parse run through the vector and remove the empty elements.  `v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), ""), v.end());`.  This even lets you handle `1/2/3////4`

Comment: @NathanOliver I see your point but I may need the empty intervals in some cases. Only the first causes problems to me. Can I use a "character set" with boost::is_any_of?

Comment: Seriously, I don't understand the downvotes. I want to split a string that starts with the delimiter character.

Comment: Not sure.  I guess because the simple thing to do would be to start after the first character.

Comment: Not a downvoter but it doesn't seem like you put much thought into solving the problem yourself.

Comment: My code is a small snippet. In real cases, I don't have argv[1] but an std::string. I don't want to use substr() since it creates a new string. I could start with the index=1 for the string, but how can I do this without creating an new std::string?

Comment: @cateof In that case I think you would be much better off writing your own function and discard the first element if it is blank.  You can see how to write your own here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just throw away the first character:

```
boost::split(v, argv[1] + 1, [](char c){return c == '/';});
```

But remember to make sure that the `strlen` of `argv[1]` is `>0` at this point